# how to fix " icon cannot be resolved to a type" error, when using a ImageIcon function

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm actually creating a program using buttons, while trying to insert the picture in the button it gives me an error saying "icon cannot be resolved to a type"

```
public class gui extends JFrame {

    private JButton reg;
    private JButton custom;

    public gui(){

        super("the title");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());//this sets a default layout

        reg =new JButton("reg button");
        add(reg);

                 .....
        //the  error here says icon cannot be resolved to a type
                //icon is highlighted for the error
            Icon b = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("b.png"));
        Icon x = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("x.jpeg"));

                 ....

        custom =new JButton("custom",b);
        custom.setRolloverIcon(x);
        add(custom);

        HandlerClass handler = new HandlerClass();
        reg.addActionListener(handler);
        custom.addActionListener(handler);  
    }

    private class HandlerClass implements ActionListener{

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent eve){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"this works");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,String.format("%S",eve.getActionCommand()));



        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You haven't shown your imports. Are you importing [`Icon`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/Icon.html)? If not, why not? You're using it as the type of `b` and `x`.

Comment: Did you import the package javax.swing.Icon?

Comment: thank you ..  but even after i import **Icon** i get an error saying  _ImageIcon.<init>(unknown Source)_ . this shows after the compilation